# Undefined behaviour in (X)HTML?

Tags: html, xhtml, undefined-behavior

### Is there such a thing as undefined behaviour in (X)HTML?

I have wondered this after playing around with the `<button>` tag, which allows HTML to be rendered as button. Nothing new so far...

But I noticed that one can also use the `<a>` tag. Complete example:

```
<button>
    normal text
    <b>bold text</b>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/">linked text</a>
</button>
```

This is rendered as following on Firefox:
[image]

And in Google Chrome:
[image]

Now, On firefox, the link target is *NOT* clickable, only the button... However, on Chrome, the link is clickable, and will redirect to the [IANA RFC2606 Page](https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved).

Is this undefined behaviour? Are there more cases in (X)HTML that could be described as undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a little more complex than just inspecting the DTD as given by [Yi Jiang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048834/undefined-behaviour-in-xhtml/5048880#5048880) and [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048834/undefined-behaviour-in-xhtml/5049296#5049296).

It's true that the XHTML 1.0 DTDs explicitly forbid `<a>` elements as children of `<button>` elements as given in your question. However it does not forbid `<a>` elements as *descendants* of `<button>` elements.

So

```
<button>
    normal text
    <b>bold text</b>
    <span><a href="http://www.example.com/">linked text</a></span>
</button>
```

is XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD conforming. But it has the same behavioural difference between Firefox and Chrome as the button fragment in the question.

Now, it is known that DTDs have problems describing limitations on descendant relationships, so it's maybe not surprising that the above sample is DTD conforming.

However. [Appendix B of the XHTML 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/prohibitions.html#prohibitions) normatively describes descendant limitations in addition to the DTD. It says:

> The following elements have
>   prohibitions on which elements they
>   can contain (see SGML Exclusions).
>   This prohibition applies to all depths
>   of nesting, i.e. it contains all the
>   descendant elements.
>
> **button**
>       must not contain the input, select, textarea, label, button, form,
>   fieldset, iframe or isindex elements.

Note that it does *not* contain an exclusion for the `<a>` element. So it seems that XHTML 1.0 does not prohibit the `<a>` element from being non-child descendant of `<button>` and the behaviour in this case is indeed undefined.

This omission is almost certainly a mistake. The `<a>` element *should* have been in the list of elements prohibited as descendants of button in Appendix B.

[HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) (including XHTML5) is much more thorough on the matter. It says:

> 4.10.8 The button element
>
> Content model:
>       Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

where [interactive content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/content-models.html#interactive-content) is defined as

> Interactive content is content that is
>   specifically intended for user
>   interaction.
>
> - `a`
> - `audio` (if the `controls` attribute is present)
> - `button`
> - `details`
> - `embed`
> - `iframe`
> - `img` (if the `usemap` attribute is present)
> - `input` (if the `type` attribute is not in the `Hidden` state)
> - `keygen`
> - `label`
> - `menu` (if the `type` attribute is in the `toolbar` state)
> - `object` (if the `usemap` attribute is present)
> - `select`
> - `textarea`
> - `video` (if the `controls` attribute is present)

So in (X)HTML5 the `<a>` element *is* prohibited from being a descendant of the `<button>` element.

Comment: Very interesting. However, I find it strange you make reference to *(X)HTML5*. There was only ever a XHTML2 planned (but later abandoned), so shouldn't HTML5 be the next version of both HTML4 and XHTML1?

Comment: @Yi Jiang. The naming of HTML5 is itself absurdly complicated. The W3C call it "HTML5", WHATWG just "living HTML". It contains a specification which covers both the HTML serialization (syntax) and the XHTML serialization, as well a lot of common ground (e.g. the content model). There are however a lot of people who still think that HTML5 doesn't cover XHTML, so I just used (X)HTML5 as a short hand to make it clear that both serializations were included.

Comment: You may be overlooking the fact that the `<A>` element is an ANCHOR element and, as such, can be used to bookmark part of a document. Accordingly, there's no reason that it should be considered an invalid descendant of a `<BUTTON>` element. Perhaps this indicative of a problem with the `<A>` element being overloaded rather than a fault with your reasoning (which, for the record, I agree with).

Comment: @Dancrumb - Good point. However, if that were the reason for allowing non-child `<a>` descendants of `<button>`, why would direct children be disallowed? Given that in HTML4 any element can act as the destination point of an anchor, and that the use case for needing to place an anchor destination inside a button is very weak anyway, I doubt that it is sufficient justification for allowing this case.

Comment: @Dancrumb: please remember that creating a named anchor using the `a` element is [obsolete in HTML 5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features) (BTW, the  WHATWG called their child that way until they moved to a rolling-release structure recently).

Answer (score 4):

The [HTML 4 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) declares the `<button>` as such:

```
<!ELEMENT BUTTON - -
     (%flow;)* -(A|%formctrl;|FORM|FIELDSET)
     -- push button -->
```

Which, **if** my reading of the DTD is correct (and I'm not exactly familiar with this), `<a>` elements are explicitly forbidden from being nested in `button`s, so what you're looking at there is invalid HTML, and therefore it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Can you clarify what part of the DTD means that `<a>` is prohibited?  What about XHTML?  The OP was asking about XHTML?  Thanks.

Comment: @jmort253: "-(A|%formctrl;|FORM|FIELDSET)" disallows `<a>`, `<form>`, `<fieldset>`, and form controls (such as `<button>`, `<input>`, ...).

Comment: @jmort253: I've added an answer with an XHTML DTD reference.

Answer (score 4):

[XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict) says this about `<button>`:

```
<!-- button uses %Flow; but excludes a, form and form controls -->
<!ENTITY % button.content
   "(#PCDATA | p | %heading; | div | %lists; | %blocktext; |
    table | %special; | %fontstyle; | %phrase; | %misc;)*">
```

So `<a>` is explicitly excluded from XHTML as well. The allowable elements inside `<button>` appear to be pretty much the same in XHTML-1.0 as in HTML-4.0.

Comment: This is  the more correct answer because the OP asked for XHTML specifically, not HTML4.

Comment: @jmort253: Thanks but it could go either way as XHTML is, more or less, an XML-ification (and hence a strict-ification) of HTML4 so they're generally the same if you ignore the sloppiness that HTML allows. Quoting from the XSD version of the XHTML specification would be more pedantically correct but I find DTDs to be easier to read than XSD.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Alohci's good answer, but more specifically to answer the question: If your (X)HTML is *invalid*, behaviour is always, *per definitionem*, undefined. In this case, browsers are free to interpret the markup as they like (or whatever chance will make out of it), or even to reject it (what no real browser does).

This is exactly the problem that the tag soup introduced and that was the origin of XML's strict parsing rules and the HTML5 spec growing to >500 pages.